# Binding a subscriber socket and connecting a publisher socket in ZeroMQ is giving error when the code is run. Why?

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe

In this code the Subscriber ( in `subscriber.cpp` code ) socket binds to port 5556.

It receives updates/messages from publisher ( in `subscriber.cpp` ), and publisher socket connects to the subscriber at 5556 and sends updates/messages to it.

I know that convention is to `.bind()` a publisher and not to call `.connect()` on it. But by theory every socket type can `.bind()` or `.connect()`.

But, both the codes give zmq error when run. **Why?**

This is CPP code.

**`publisher.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zhelpers.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main () {

zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);
publisher.connect("tcp://*:5556");
while (1) {

    zmq::message_t request (12);
    memcpy (request.data (), "Pub-1 Data", 12);
    sleep(1);
    publisher.send (request);
}
return 0;
}
```

---

**`subcriber.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5556");
subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0); // subscribe to all messages

//  Process 10 updates
int update_nbr;
for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 10 ; update_nbr++) {

    zmq::message_t update;
    subscriber.recv (&update);
    std::string updt = std::string(static_cast<char*>(update.data()), update.size());
    std::cout << "Received Update/Messages/TaskList " << update_nbr <<" : "<< updt << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `theory every socket type can bind or connect` no - udp doesn't make connections. You bind to a port on both sides and send data to the other end... nothing ensures that the data will be received; or will tell you that it is

Comment: Okay. But please tell why above code fails.@UKMonkey

Comment: I'd have to install zeromq; take your code; and then follow the steps in https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/   It would help if you said what the error was; but learning to debug your own programs is somewhat essential before attempting to do such complex tasks as this

Comment: Would you kindly also post the ZeroMQ version + zmq_error number + where it has actually happened? ( **all the normal debugging details** )

Comment: Version : 4.2.3   After I run the program ,this is the output that I get: for publisher.cpp
 "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  Invalid argument
Aborted" 
For subscriber.cpp:" terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  No such device
Aborted"

Comment: UPDATE: The code is working when I changed the line -
 subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5556"); to subscriber.bind("tcp://*:5556");      and   
 publisher.connect("tcp://*:5556"); to publisher.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");

Answer (score 1):

### No, there is no problem in reversed `.bind()/.connect()`

This principally works fine.

Yet, the **`PUB/SUB`** Formal Archetype is [**subject** to a so called **late-joiner syndrome**.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26688152)

Without thorough debugging details, as were requested above, one may just repeat general rules of thumb:

In newer API versions one may
add `rc = <aSocket>.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE,  1 ); assert( rc & "CONFLATE"  );`
add `rc = <aSocket>.setsockopt( ZMQ_IMMEDIATE, 1 ); assert( rc & "IMMEDIATE" );`
and so forth,
all that to better tune the context-instance + socket-instance attributes, so as to minimise the late-joiner syndrome effects.

Comment: UPDATE: The code is working when I changed the line -
 subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5556"); to subscriber.bind("tcp://*:5556");      and   
 publisher.connect("tcp://*:5556"); to publisher.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");

Comment: Right, error traces may look mystic, but clear - the 1st is related to symbolic-name translation, the 2nd is a residual nonsense from a SLOC being manually changed / edited from .bind() method, where it had sense to .connect(), where wildcard expansion lost the sense. **Glad you have debugged down to the root cause.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with reversed bind()/connect().
The code is working when I changed the line - subscriber.bind("tcp://localhost:5556"); 
to 
subscriber.bind("tcp://*:5556"); 
and 
publisher.connect("tcp://*:5556"); 
to
publisher.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");