# How could MQL4 communicate with python?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, mql4, trading, low-latency

I want to communicate with each other the modes I wrote in the python programming language with MQL4, which is the fastest way to do this? Can there be another solution in this regard that zeromq seems difficult to install and use?

Comment: MQL4 can use WebSockets, yet better use the ZeroMQ extension ( an add-on option via DLL ). Having used this for 11+ years in driving distributed FX systems, you will love the latter way more than a sandboxed former. May start a first view from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682634/differences-between-zeromq-and-websockets/26688152#26688152 and my enjoy a fast help to get a brief grasp of the ZeroMQ composition here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571