# Custom message between jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zeromq, messaging

Is it possible to use ZMQ part of Anaconda for custom messaging between jupyter notebooks somehow? My intention is that if there is a boundled solution why should I write my own comm solution, or install something new :-)
I would like to query all available notebooks and if the required one is up and running then I want to send custom, streamed data to that notebok. (Previously I made it with asyncio socket server/client architecture with pure .py scripts).

Unfortunately the [messaging documentation](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#messaging) does not help me too much.

Thank you in advance!

sm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Is it possible to use ZMQ part of Anaconda for custom messaging between jupyter notebooks somehow?"*

Sure.

**Option A :**
One may extend the jupyter framework to include all your new functionalities in FOSS core

**Option B :**
One may instantiate one's own ZeroMQ signaling / messaging infrastructure on top of & independent from the jupyter internal signaling / messaging functionalities, and work just with a pure user-level code.

```
include zmq

my1stContextINSTANCE = zmq.context()                          # The Engine
my1stPublisherSOCKET = my1stContextINSTANCE.socket( zmq.PUB ) #        its Socket
my1stPublisherSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER,       0 )        #            configurations
my1stPublisherSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SNDBUF, 2000000 )        #            ...
...
my1stPullDataSOCKET  = my1stContextINSTANCE.socket( zmq.PULL )#        its Socket
my1stPullDataSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER,        0 )        #            configurations
my1stPullDataSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.RCVBUF,   100000 )        #            ...

...

while True:
   ...
   my1stPublisherSOCKET.send( "INF: message payload[{0:}]".format( repr( _ ) ) )
   ...
   if ( my1stPullDataSOCKET.poll( 0 ) ) ... ):
       ...

   elseif:
       ...

   else:
       ...

   continue
```

---

Reciprocally the same on all the other peer-sides.

The ZeroMQ framework is smart for doing this, either way. You may like to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682634/differences-between-zeromq-and-websockets/26688152#26688152) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729055/understanding-advanced-zeromq-socket-types/25742744#25742744).

The architecture design & the implementation wisdom & robustness is yours.

Comment: Thank you! It helped! I thought I have to install a messaging infrastructure (a cluster or something) to make it work, but it is "just" an importable library. Great! Merry XMath :-)

Comment: Boldog Karácsonyt! @spyder