# Mimic ZeroMQ SUB-Socket (in a PUB/SUB system) with e.g. Socket/WebSocket in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, tcp, zeromq

Community,

I want to `use`/`subscribe` a `pub`-socket on a server that implements ZeroMQ (https://zeromq.org/)

My final product will be a flutter app. It must be running on Android/iOS/Windows/MacOS/Linux/Web. So I'm **really careful** with the plugin-choice. I do not want to burden myself with an intense amount of platform-specific code, neither do I want to be dependent on plugins that might `break` under certain conditions on each platform.

I know that there is a [ZeroMQ-Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/), but it has some [Unresolved Issues](https://github.com/enwi/dartzmq/issues/5) in terms of operability on different platforms. Also I tried to run it on different Windows-machines and it only worked in about 25% of the cases.

Here's the fundamental network-communication between App and Server (see image below).

Is it possible to connect to a ZeroMQ-Publisher-Socket WITHOUT implementing or depending on the C++ compiled file of ZeroMQ? I'm thinking of a `Socket` or `WebSocket`, but I'm not even sure if it's technically possible (protocol etc), as I think that ZeroMQ uses it's own protocoll (please verify).

Can I subscribe to a ZeroMQ-Publisher-Socket with `Sockets` or `WebSockets` in Flutter? If yes, how? Are there alternatives?

[image: Flutter App trying to connect to a ZeroMQ Server]dartzmq/install

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q1 :**
> *"Is it possible to connect to a ZeroMQ-Publisher-Socket WITHOUT implementing or depending on the C++ compiled file of ZeroMQ?"*

**A1 :**
Yes, it is. It is quite enough to re-implement the published ZeroMQ ZMTP RFC-s relevant for the use-case & your code is granted to become interoperable, irrespective of the implementation language / deployment ecosystem, if it meets all the ZMTP RFC-s' mandatory requirements. So it is doable.

> **Q2 :**
> *"... ZeroMQ uses it's own protocoll (please verify)."*

**A2 :**
No, in the sense of OSI-ISO-L2/L3 stack.
Yes, in the sense of higher layer application-driven protocols, where the ZMTP RFC-s apply for the most of the ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Patterns' Archetypes ( *may read more on [ZeroMQ sockets are not sockets as you know them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682634/differences-between-zeromq-and-websockets/26688152#26688152)* ), yet there are also tools to interface with O/S plain-sockets' *`fd`*-s, where needed. Still A1 applies here.

> **Q3 :**
> *"Can I subscribe to a ZeroMQ-Publisher-Socket with ...? If yes, how?"*

**A3 :**
Yes, it possible when your code follows the published ZMTP RFC-s. Implement all ZMTP RFC-s' mandatory properties & you are granted an interoperability with any other, ZeroMQ-ZMTP-RFC-s' compliant, node.

> **Q4 :**
> *"Are there alternatives?"*

**A4 :**
Yes, if your design can extend the Server-side, adding another AccessPoint-s there, using `ZMQ_STREAM` Scalable Formal Communication Archetype there, may reduce your Flutter-side scope of ZMTP RFC-s needed, as interfacing to native plain-socket will be the only one to handle and the "functionality gap" thereof can be handled on the Server-side of the link ( easily handling all the subscription management & message filtering, that must meet the ZeroMQ ZMTP RFC-s, so why not tandem it inside the Server-side before connecting the down-stream to Flutter App - smart, isn't it? )