# iOS SwiftyZeroMQ get status

Tags: ios, swift, zeromq

I am using SwiftyZeroMQ in iOS for zeromq. I can connect and communicate via sockets. But issue is I can't find anyway to know how can I get event/status that socket connection has failed?

like  `let result = zmq_connect(handle, endpoint)` always return 0 in result

Comment: Checking the result is the correct way. However ZeroMQ socket are not plain (TCP/IP) sockets. `zmq_connect` usually succeeds because it does not need the peer to be reachable. ZeroMQ sockets will connect (and reconnect) when needed, for example when you start sending or receiving data.

Answer (score -1):

> …how can I get event/status that socket connection has failed?

The first step is to forget everything about native-sockets, as ZeroMQ `Socket()`-instances are different.

To start understanding the concept, perhaps start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615141/how-to-control-the-source-ip-address-of-a-zeromq-packet-on-a-machine-with-multip/46620571#46620571) to get the global view of the composition of:

- what is the Scalable Formal Communications (behavioural pattern) Archetype
- what is the engine - the actual signalling/messaging serving **`Context()`**
- what is the ***AccessPoint*** (to be `.bind()`-exposed to public and so `.connect()`-ed as & when needed)

Having got these abstractions, one soon realises the real-world applications seldom rely on just one pattern, most often there are many, app-level cooperating (possibly also in many-to-many topologies) connections, like noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682634/differences-between-zeromq-and-websockets/26688152#26688152)

Last, but not least, there are low-level details we may source from our abstracted Scalable Formal Communication Archetypes' AccessPoints, if using a ZeroMQ API documented `socket_monitor()` and set it up so as to feed many low-level events we normally do not want to see in production. ZeroMQ API documentation is instrumental in how to do this, yet your iOS-specific native-API binding may, yet need not, cover this in your current language-binding, so start first with the SwiftyZeroMQ documentation, if it covers also this ZeroMQ native-API functions.